# How to write a snapshot test for Chartjs react-chart-js-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm struggling with understanding how to write a snapshot test to mock the Chart.js component.

Example (BubbleGraph is a component that renders the Chart):

```js
const renderComponent = () =>
    render(
      <Provider store={mockStore}>
        <BubbleGraph {...props} />
      </Provider>
    )
```

I've done the below, but that means the chart does not render in the snapshot at all.

```js
jest.mock('react-chartjs-2', () => ({
  Chart: () => null,
}))
```

How can I make chart render in the snapshot with the props that i'm passing?

Comment: I'm having this problem with it and `storybook`.